# Taking slowlogs that are having TOOK field greater than 15ms using logstash?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

LOGS:

```
[2017-01-14 10:48:06,848][WARN ][index.search.slowlog.query] [yaswanth] [bank][0] took[27.8ms], took_millis[27], types[], stats[], search_type[QUERY_THEN_FETCH], total_shards[5], source[], extra_source[], 
[2017-01-14 10:48:06,851][WARN ][index.search.slowlog.query] [yaswanth] [bank][3] took[12.7ms], took_millis[33], types[], stats[], search_type[QUERY_THEN_FETCH], total_shards[5], source[], extra_source[],
```

I am trying to get the logs whose TOOK field is >15ms . I used the below config

```
input {
  file {
    path => "F:\logstash-2.4.0\logstash-2.4.0\pica.txt"
    start_position => "beginning"
  }
}

filter {
           grok {
                match => [ "message", "\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:TIMESTAMP}\]\[%{LOGLEVEL:LEVEL}%{SPACE}\]\[%{DATA:QUERY}\]%{SPACE}\[%{DATA:QUERY1}\]%{SPACE}\[%{DATA:INDEX-NAME}\]\[%{DATA:SHARD}\]%{SPACE}took\[%{DATA:TOOK}\],%{SPACE}took_millis\[%{DATA:TOOKM}\], types\[%{DATA:types}\], stats\[%{DATA:stats}\], search_type\[%{DATA:search_type}\], total_shards\[%{NUMBER:total_shards}\], source\[%{DATA:source_query}\], extra_source\[%{DATA:extra_source}\],"]
           }
if [TOOK] > 15ms {
    mutate {
      add_tag => "slowresponse"
    }
  } else {
    drop { }
  }
}
output {
stdout { codec => rubydebug }

}
```

The error is like this:

```
[31mException in pipelineworker, the pipeline stopped processing new events, please check your filter configuration and restart Logstash. {"exception"=>#<NoMethodError: undefined method `>' for nil:NilClass>, "backtrace"=>["(eval):123:in `initialize'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'", "(eval):121:in `initialize'", "org/jruby/RubyProc.java:281:in `call'", "(eval):91:in `filter_func'", "F:/logstash-2.4.0/logstash-2.4.0/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.4.0-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:267:in `filter_batch'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'", "org/jruby/RubyEnumerable.java:852:in `inject'", "F:/logstash-2.4.0/logstash-2.4.0/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.4.0-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:265:in `filter_batch'", "F:/logstash-2.4.0/logstash-2.4.0/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.4.0-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:223:in `worker_loop'", "F:/logstash-2.4.0/logstash-2.4.0/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.4.0-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:201:in `start_workers'"], :level=>:error}[0m
NoMethodError: undefined method `>' for nil:NilClass
     initialize at (eval):123
           each at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613
     initialize at (eval):121
           call at org/jruby/RubyProc.java:281
    filter_func at (eval):91
   filter_batch at F:/logstash-2.4.0/logstash-2.4.0/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.4.0-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:267
           each at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613
         inject at org/jruby/RubyEnumerable.java:852
   filter_batch at F:/logstash-2.4.0/logstash-2.4.0/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.4.0-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:265
    worker_loop at F:/logstash-2.4.0/logstash-2.4.0/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.4.0-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:223
  start_workers at F:/logstash-2.4.0/logstash-2.4.0/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.4.0-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:201
```

I want to see the logs that are having TOOK field greater than 15ms. I even tried it by giving `"15ms"`.

THANKS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to use the `TOOKM` field instead of the `TOOK` field since it contains a numeric value which is easier to compare than a string one. Also you need to convert `TOOKM` to an integer using `mutate/convert`.

The modified configuration which will help you achieve what you want is here:

```
input {
  file {
    path => "F:\logstash-2.4.0\logstash-2.4.0\pica.txt"
    start_position => "beginning"
  }
}

filter {
    grok {
       match => [ "message", "\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:TIMESTAMP}\]\[%{LOGLEVEL:LEVEL}%{SPACE}\]\[%{DATA:QUERY}\]%{SPACE}\[%{DATA:QUERY1}\]%{SPACE}\[%{DATA:INDEX-NAME}\]\[%{DATA:SHARD}\]%{SPACE}took\[%{DATA:TOOK}\],%{SPACE}took_millis\[%{DATA:TOOKM}\], types\[%{DATA:types}\], stats\[%{DATA:stats}\], search_type\[%{DATA:search_type}\], total_shards\[%{NUMBER:total_shards}\], source\[%{DATA:source_query}\], extra_source\[%{DATA:extra_source}\],"]
    }

    # ==> add this filter to convert TOOKM to integer
    mutate {
        convert => { "TOOKM" => "integer" }
    }

    # ==> use TOOKM field instead
    if [TOOKM] > 15 {
        mutate {
            add_tag => "slowresponse"
        }
    } else {
        drop { }
    }
}
output {
   stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Val, Is their a proper format to parse the errors of elasticsearch in the same way we parse slowlogs?

Comment: Val can you help me on this logstash configuration http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43897265/combining-multiple-message-fields-using-multiline-codec-in-logstash/43898098?noredirect=1#comment74831302_43898098

Answer (score 0):

That exception will occur if the field does not exist:

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/comparing-number-in-conditionnal-event-treatement/217043/5